# Vue.js devtools Chrome extension is broken - the Vuex tab is empty and Components tab only show after Refresh

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-devtools, vuex

I see the following behavior in my Vue.js devtools extension in Chrome:

- When I open the Vue-tab in Chrome developer tools the Components tab is empty.
- When I click Refresh the components show up.
- When I open the Vuex tab it says "No Vuex store detected."
- Even if I click refresh here it doesn't help.

Can anybody suggest what can be wrong? It worked previously but suddenly it is broken.

More details: 
- I run Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Mac
- I just re-installed the Vue.js Devtools extension today.

Answer (score 2):

It was caused by bugs in the code. After fixing the code the vue tools worked again.

Answer (score 2):

If Vuex store is in a separate file or folder, please add `Vue.config.devtools = true` before new Vuex.store statement.

Answer (score 0):

> When I open the Vuex tab it says "No Vuex store detected.

Maybe there is an error in your store module. Is Vuex in use and imported?

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)
```

Comment: Yes, we have these lines of code. We don't have any warnings about errors in the Vuex store. Also the console says: [vue-devtools] Ready. Detected Vue v2.4.1

Comment: I have the same: `Ready. Detected Vue 2.5.9` but Vuex  reads: "**No Vuex store detected.**" even though I can see data in my page that is updating via Vuex.

Comment: Found the answer to my  _personal_ issue here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/391#issuecomment-344995974
I realize I'm looking at a production build with Dev Tools turned on.  This won't work with Vuex.